# Memory leak when using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a very simple application using EF. But when it runs a week, the memory usage is awful (only 80MB at first, 700MB after one week).
When I use dotMemory to profile my application. I find the memory of Heap generation 2 is increasing all the time.

[image: only run 40 minutes]

I Get a snapshot, finally find the retained bytes of ef dbcontext is the most.

[image]

I am so confused. My application is so simple. Code sample：

```
protected CarbonBrushMonitorEntities _entities = new MYEntities();
public void Add(HistoryData data)
{
   _entities.HistoryDatas.Add(data);
   _entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

`_entities` only initials once at the starting time, then used all the time.

The function `Add` is frequently called，about 3 times/second

I google a long time, and try some methods such as:

```
_entities.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
_entities.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
_entities.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

but these do not work.

Comment: How do you manage the lifetime of your EF context? Do you ever dispose/re-create it?

Comment: @ken2k create at the starting time, then used all the time. never dispose/re-created. Because my application Architecture uses Ioc and Dependency Injection。

Comment: What class is the add method in?

Comment: Why is using IoC excuse for not using UnitOfWork / LifetimeScope?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you use entity framework, you should **create the context just before you need it** and **dispose it as soon as possible**:

```
 using (var someContext = new SomeContext())
 {
    // your commands/queries
 }
```

Never keep context in memory or share it across different calls.

What I typically do is register the context with an IoC container:

```
 DependencyFactory.RegisterType(typeof(SomeContext));
```

and use a context resolver (also registered with IoC of course) like:

```
 using (var someContext = _contextResolver.ResolveContext())
 {
     // your commands/queries
 }
```

where resolution is done like:

```
 public class ContextResolver : IContextResolver
 {
     public ISomeContext ResolveContext()
     {
          return DependencyFactory.Resolve<SomeContext>();
     }
 }
```

The EF context is actually your unit of work, which should be disposed of once you don't need it anymore.

Comment: To also add it is not thread safe! and so no reason to keep it/share it between threads.

Comment: Can you suggest an article or tutorial about that? Thanks.

Comment: Yuck! The `ContextResolver` knows about `DependencyFactory`. Nice service locator anti-pattern going on there ...

Comment: If you are purist, or you think this will give you actual problems, you could abstract this out.

Answer (score 11):

The other way is to clear the changetracker of the respective entities of concern or even 
of all the entities. This is done by changing the entity state to "Detached". This called after `dbContext.SaveChangesAsync()`

```
protected void DisposeDbset<T>() where T : class
        {
            var Tname = typeof(T).Name;
            var changetrackercollection = _unitOfWork.dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<T>();
            foreach (var item in changetrackercollection.ToList())
            {
                item.State = EntityState.Detached;
            }
            GC.Collect();
        }
```

I recently faced a similar situation where I was inserting 3,00,000 rows in batch operation. After inserting the rows, the change tracking info for all the rows remained in the memory with the entity state as Unchanged. Hence after every `SaveChangesAsync()` call, the changetracker accumulated.

I could not resolve new instance dbcontext for every batch, as it was a more expensive operation.

Just FYI, i had configured `dbConetext.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = NoTracking`.  But this is applicable to while fetching the data.

Hopefully this is helpful. I found my solution with the help of this link http://andreyzavadskiy.com/2016/09/23/entries-in-entity-framework-changetracker-could-degrade-database-write-performance/?unapproved=19301&moderation-hash=4acc61a32ead7232959c2ec1ca268180#comment-19301

Comment: I am facing the same issue, can you please let me know how did you fix this issue.

Comment: @Ravikumar After calling SaveCahngesAsync() on the dbContext, call the above method by the passing the name of the entity which is causing a memory leak.

Comment: I use the above code in the Dispose(bool disposing) method of my DbContext.

Comment: @Chintanshah, Did you try SQLBulkCopy?

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Chintan shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9245574/chintan-shah) answer I made an `extension method` and an example.

```cs
public static class DbContextExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Set all entries in ChangeTracker to detached to get them collected by the GC
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public static void DetachAllEntriesInChangeTracker(this DbContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var entityEntry in context.ChangeTracker.Entries())
            {
                entityEntry.State = EntityState.Detached;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogManager.GetLogger(context.GetType().FullName).Error(e, "error when detaching all entries in changeTracker");
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
public class FooDbContext : DbContext
{
    public override void Dispose()
    {
        this.DetachAllEntriesInChangeTracker();
        base.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Bad solution. If you dispose a context the problem is already gone, see the accepted answer. This `Dispose` override only takes more time. The point of this Q&A is that people should adhere to a healthy context life cycle. When these detach tricks are necessary that usually spells trouble in the life cycle area.

Comment: In my project I'm actually using a `DbContextScope` library and also `Lamar` and `AspNet` for `dependencyInjection`. But I still have that memory leak, that the `DbContext` is not removed from memory after disposing. After examining it with [dotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/), I was able to successfully solve it by using `DetachAllEntriesInChangeTracker()` in my `Dispose()`. In principle, however, I am of your opinion that this should not be necessary.

Comment: That makes this solution highly specific. It's certainly not widely applicable and IMO not fit for a Stack overflow answer because it may encourage bad practice. Even in your case you'd do better digging deeper to get to the bottom of this memory leek. Maybe you have long-lived proxy objects that keep references to the contexts they were created with.

Comment: i am on latest update update of ef fore dotnet core 3.1. running several test background services in aspnet doing read/update/delete/dispose. dipose only did not help for sure. so killed change tracking stuff directly. not sure if AsNoTracking alone helps either.