# Should I explicitly dispose dbContext that reads from a single table that nothing will ever write to?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I create a service that reads from a single table through EF `dbContext`.

- The `dbContext` is created in this service based on given connection string
- The `dbContext` is private
- The service exclusively reads from this table and never writes to it
- No other contexts use this table, altough they use other tables in the same database
- This table doesn't consist any foreign keys

**Question:** Having in mind all above should I dispose the context in this service by using a `using` statement? If yes, why?

I don't want to have to do it because it complicates tests extensively, but if I have to then by all means I'll do it.

Comment: `I don't want to have to do it because it complicates tests extensively` Can you show us an example of such a test, just to confirm there isn't a way to do it in a way that doesn't complicate the tests extensively?

Comment: I'd argue, that using EF for reading a single table is a bit of overkill.

Comment: If you are always reading with `AsNoTracking()` and also never use it from multiple threads - you should probably be fine in this case.

Comment: Just a thought, but if that is a strict readonly access, why use EF at all? I usually just use Dapper to SELECT the data in such a use case.

Comment: [Do I always have to call Dispose() on my DbContext objects? Nope](https://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always initialize a context as late as possible and dispose it as soon as possible. If you don't do this, the context will keep growing and might start behaving like a memory leak, eventually giving you memory issues.

To do this, use `using` statement; or if you use a DI framework, use a lifetime that ends after each web request or something similar.

Also see: [Memory leak when using Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209528/memory-leak-when-using-entity-framework)

"It makes tests more complicated" is absolutely no reason for not following best practices. Not sure what you mean with that, either.

Comment: You can add, that DataContext instantiation is a cheap operation. If it uses connection pool, no new connection will be established